# Visual Studio WCF Application now asking to manually attach to process

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, debugging

I have a console app that is calling a WCF app hosted in IIS.

Up until now everything has been fine and I am able to debug the app - step through it without any problems...

Until I added my dev pc to a domain.... now every time I get step into the code hosted in IIS, a popup comes up asking if I would like to attach to this process...

I can then continue debugging... again not a huge train smash - however... now it randomly just jumps to the end of the process (almost like some kind of timeout) and I am not able to reliably step and debug the IIS hosted code....

Any ideas?

All the projects are in the same solution, and all running on the local dev pc... Using Visual Studio 2008, dev PC is Win 7

Comment: @JL: I am also having the same problem, for my asp.net apps. I am using VS2008. Can you also mention your VS version in the post ?

Comment: Next thing I'd try would be to disconnect the pc from the network and verify that the previous behavior still occurs.  Let us know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regards to the timeout, have you tried modifying the timeout settings on the binding being used? Otherwise the waiting client will process the timeout when it's hit, even if you're still debugging hosted code. For dev purposes, something that I've found useful is to have a debug binding that I can switch to with exagerated settings for message sizes and timeouts to prevent this like below:

```
      <wsHttpBinding><binding name="DebugDefaultHttp" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
      receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
      transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000" messageEncoding="Text"
      textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
        enabled="false" />
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
          algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="false" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
```

Comment: Guys your suggestions are good and noted, but what I really want to know if why the sudden need to manually attach to process, when before I joined the domain I had seamless debugging....

Answer (score 1):

Yup, timeouts can be a real pain with debugging.

Another thing that I do is I often write a small console program to host my service so that I can connect to that for debugging purposes.  That way, I don't have to attach to a remote service for debugging purposes.